# Manipular archivos .csv usando (fgetcsv()) php

Tags: php, csv

Busco una manera de comparar y añadir datos a un archivo **csv** usando php.

Asta el momento e logrado este código usando

> fgetcsv()

Aunque no funciona al 100% por que no logro resolver algunos detalles:

Este es el contenido de "datos.csv"

```
15,carlos
28,fran
36,luis
44,norlan
```

Esta es el código que intenta comparar resultados :

```
<?php
$id = '36';
$f = fopen("datos.csv", "r");
$result = false;
while ($row = fgetcsv($f, 0, ",")) {
        if ($row[0] == $id) {
            $result = $row[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($f);
echo $result;

?>
```

Lo que busco es comparar la variable **$id** con todas las columna A si lo encuentra Devuelve los datos que haya en la columna B .

Aun no funciona espero alguna idea.

Otro dato que me interesa es como añadir el valor de **$id**  que no encuentre en el archivo "datos.csv" a la columna A y otro valor a la columna B.

Comment: Porque no te funciona? te da algún error? en el while estas usando como separador `;` y en el Contenido de **datos.csv** el separador es una `,`

Comment: Sera ese el error ? revisare

Comment: Gracias por el dato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buscando una solución en san google encontré información y esta es la forma correcta:

```
$s= '36';
$f = fopen("demos.csv", "r");
$result = false;
while ($row = fgetcsv($f, 0, ",")) {
        if ($row[0] == $s) {
            $result = $row[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($f);
echo $result;
```

y para almacenar los datos se usa esta manera:

```
$id = '1';
$name= 'alfredo';

$file = fopen('demos.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($file, array($id, $name));
fclose($file);
```

Espero le resulte útil a alguien Saludes